# Why do I sometimes get EQT_{guid} folders with copies of my application when running MsTest unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have noticed on occasion (not very frequently) that after I run my suite of MsTest unit tests in Visual Studio, I will get a folder or folders that are of the form (the guid varies):

```
EQT_6A69DAE9-1C34-4B96-8B96-698A94EA1ADF
```

The folder will only contain a copy of my `.exe` file for the application.  In this case, the application is using WPF.

These folders always show up inside my `Debug` directory.

There is nowhere in my application that I am creating anything like this (and certainly not copying my own .exe file), so it appears to be a product of something in MsTest.

Why does MsTest sometimes create this folder with a copy of just my `.exe` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are the runs that would have code coverage enabled via your .testsettings file. Your .exe is being backed up here while an instrumented version is created for code coverage when running with .testsettings.

This will not happen when you run code coverage without any .testsettings using the "Analyze code coverage" option available in VS2012